# Using .htacces to run a .ics file as a .php file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm tyring to use .htaccess to run a .ics file as a .php file so that I can use the PHP code to create a calendar, that will then be recognized by devices like iPhones or programs like Microsoft Outlook since it's file extension is .ics. I haven't been able to get it to work so came here to see if someone could help.

.htacces code: 
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .ics

I'm not sure if it's an error with .htaccess or with something in the PHP code, so if I need to post the PHP code please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: It's easier (and safer) to use mod_rewrite to rewrite .ics to .php ones. Or actually, you can probably just use a `Content-Disposition: attachment;` header.

Answer (score 1):

If you try and access the .ics file, and then open the contents in notepad or whatever, do you still see the  tags?

Comment: If you mean PHP tags, then yes, they were all still there

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .ics
```

Comment: @Wrikken, You are simply trying to add a handler. It does not provide which hosting provider.

Comment: THen again `application/x-httpd-php5s` is not recognized on any server besides bluehost's as far as I know. `application/x-httpd-php5` yes, `application/x-httpd-php` also, but `application/x-httpd-php5s` I only encuontered on bluehost. At the very least, it is far from default for `mod_php`/`mod_php5`.

Comment: @Wrikken, You know everything dont you? I use that on the hosting from justhost too.

Comment: "Know everything"? I started with a _question_ dear grasshopper.... SO, back to my original question: "I only know bluehost to use this, or is it more widespread?" Apparently, more widespread then that, but I'd still like to know _where_ it comes from, as it still isn't default `mod_php`. Cpanel mod or something? Or don't you know and is this a 'whatever works for you, we don't need to know why' kind of answer?

Answer (score 0):

You would need something like this:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .ics
AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .ics

<FilesMatch "\.(ics|php)$">
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

I don't know if it is redundant, but I have sucessfully used something similar for `.htm` files in the past.